# Packaging MacOS CLI functionality to use on other Macs portably

Tags: node.js, macos, command-line-interface, packaging, qpdf

I wrote a node script to use with a specific PDF format that my MacOS-based company receives to automate some things. It requires the PDF file to be uncompressed, which I am using [qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) to do.

Is it possible to package up this simple functionality, which consists of one qpdf command piped into a node script I wrote, so that it can be used on other MacOS machines without installing qpdf and node on those machines?

Comment: You could do it in pure JavaScript instead with https://www.npmjs.com/package/coherentpdf